# How to get all the key-values underlying between two given keys in a sorted hashmap?

Tags: java, hashmap, hashtable, treemap

I have a HashMap with Time as key. I sorted the HashMap.
Now I want to get all the key-values between two keys i.e. time values.

Comment: A HashMap can't be sorted. I'm guessing you have a TreeMap?

Comment: Filter out those which are "before" minimal and "after" maximal data. What trouble are you facing while doing so?

Comment: As @SeanPatrickFloyd mentioned there is no such thing as sorted `HashMap`. And `TreeSet`, which **is** sorted has a built-in method for this

Comment: What have you tried ? What went wrong ? Give an example input/output ?

Comment: Do you mean a linked hash map?

Comment: Yes, a treemap @SeanPatrickFloyd

Comment: HashMap is not TreeMap. Use [edit] option to clarify your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's some example code. A [`TreeMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) implements the interface [`NavigableMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/NavigableMap.html), so make sure you use that as your variable type, to harness the full power of a `TreeMap`:

```
NavigableMap<Integer, String> map = new TreeMap<>();
// code to fill my map with values from 1 to 20, key=int, value=String.valueOf(int)
IntStream.rangeClosed(1,20).forEach(i->map.put(i, String.valueOf(i)));
```

NavigableMap has a method [`.subMap(start, end)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/NavigableMap.html#subMap-K-K-) and an overload [`.subMap(start, startInclusive, end, endInclusive)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/NavigableMap.html#subMap-K-boolean-K-boolean-) for selecting a partial view of the map, and it sounds like this is what you need.

```
NavigableMap<Integer, String> subMap = map.subMap(5, false, 10, false);
```

This is a live view of the map I created before, but it contains only the mappings between keys 5 and 10, exclusive. Let's check whether that works as expected:

```
subMap.forEach(
    (k, v) -> System.out.printf("Key: %d, value: '%s'%n", k, v)
);
```

Output:

> Key: 6, value: '6'
>   Key: 7, value: '7'
>   Key: 8, value: '8'
>   Key: 9, value: '9'

As you can see, the map remains sorted, but is limited to the specified range.